# Iterate object list with VueJs from Django API

Tags: django, vue.js

I try to iterate through a `Django Rest API` object list using `VueJS`. I can get the articles `json` list  but I can't correctly view `VueJs` template component. In my `Django` views I  use

```
<section class="blog-post-wrap medium-padding80">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div id="starting">
             <div class="" v-for="article in articles">
                <articlelist title="article.title"></articlelist>
             </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And I use VueJs component template

```
Vue.component('articlelist', {
      template: `
              <div class="col col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                  <div class="ui-block"
                          <div class="post-content">
                              <a href="#" class="post-category bg-blue-light">THE COMMUNITY</a>
                              <a href="#" class="h4 post-title">{{title}}! </a>
                              <p>Here’s a photo from last month’s photoshoot. We got really awesome shots for the new catalog.</p>
                         </div>
                      <!-- ... end Post -->
                  </div>
              </div>
              `,
              props: ['title']
          });
     new Vue({
       el: '#starting',
       delimiters: ['${','}'],
       components:{
         'articlelist': articlelist,
       },
       data: {
       articles: [],
       loading: false,
       currentArticle: {},
       message: null,
       newArticle: {
           'title': null,
           'content': null,
       },
        },
       mounted: function() {
         this.getArticles();
        },
        methods: {
         getArticles: function() {
          this.loading = true;
          this.$http.get('/api/articles/')
              .then((response) => {
                this.articles = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
                this.loading = false;
              })
              .catch((err) => {
               this.loading = false;
               console.log(err);
              })
         },
         getArticle: function(id) {
          this.loading = true;
          this.$http.get(`/api/articles/${id}/`)
              .then((response) => {
                this.currentArticle = response.data;
                this.loading = false;
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log(err);
              })
         },
         addArticle: function() {
          this.loading = true;
          this.$http.post(`/api/articles/`,this.newArticle)
              .then((response) => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.getArticles();
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log(err);
              })
         },
         updateArticle: function() {
          this.loading = true;
          this.$http.put(`/api/articles/${this.currentArticle.article_id}/`, this.currentArticle)
              .then((response) => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.currentArticle = response.data;
                this.getArticles();
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log(err);
              })
         },
         deleteArticle: function(id) {
          this.loading = true;
          this.$http.delete(`/api/articles/${id}/` )
              .then((response) => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.getArticles();
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log(err);
              })
         }
        }
     });
```

I am aware that I could not manage to correct the naming of components and scripts but I can not find the correct way.

When I check chrome dev tools, I see error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: articlelist is not defined
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: what's the problem, it's not working or, getting any error?

Comment: I am adding the error.

Comment: What's the output of  `response.data`?

Comment: I am trying to view it but it does not show with console.log. Can I send you a link of what I am trying to achive? the main problem. when I view articles with loop I cant manage the iteration.

Comment: Yes, you can provide any working link: jsFiddle, codepen or else

Comment: ok I fixed it changing the code in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188352/discussion-between-ytsejam-and-sajib-khan).

Comment: Can you provide a working link where the code can be run & get same error?

Comment: I am thinking how to solve that I have registered component in my main vue script. Now error has changed to "article is not defined" .. How do I define article ?

Comment: I have updated to solution I arrived, I have changed the code, now I can get API and json list but I cant define "article" using props.

Comment: Where is your `v-for` loop `<article-list :article="article"></article-list>` ?

Comment: it is in my html template, I have added it. This is my last form.

Comment: Done I have succeeded

Comment: I can get the loop but I cant get the article title, insteead I only see "List". I dont understand where it comes from.